# Instagram UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, instagram

if someone have Instagram on his iPhone try to tap on the raised center button in the tabbar, the button for posting new images.

It seems to present a modal view controller without animation, right?

The view controller is an UIImagePickerController with a camera overlay? I ask this because if you try to take a photo and click OKAY, you'll can see the next controller within a `UINavigationController`. In this way you can go back and retake the photo or go forward and posting it.

How this is possible? How can I present a navigation controller with an `UIImagePickerController` and push others view controller after the picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just presenting `UINavigationController` as a modal view controller on top of the `UIImagePickerController`. When you press 'Filter' button to come back to the photo, it does not navigate in a way that `UINavigationController` does. I think it is overriding the back button ('Filter' button) and dismissing the entire `UINavigationController`.

What I found interesting was that when the `UINavigationController` shows up, there is an animation that slides the new view from right to left. My guess is that the `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController` is an empty transparent view, and the next view (that contains caption and sharing option etc) is pushed on the navigation stack after short delay.

I didn't think about it, but it is interesting to observe! :)

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer dude! When you say "I think it is just presenting UINavigationController as a modal view controller on top of the UIImagePickerController." how can I present `UINavigationController` as a modal view controller on top of UIImagePickerController? Should I do this from `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method?

Comment: Honestly, I doubt if the previous screen of the navigation view is `UIImagePickerController`. You take photo by clicking 'camera' button and then it dismisses `UIImagePickerController`, shows the filter view. Filter view I think is just a custom view presented as a modal view controller. And yes, I think this custom filter view is presented in `[UIImagePickerControllerDelegate imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]`, after dismissing the `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: The problem is that I can't present a modal view controller in `[UIImagePickerControllerDelegate imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]` after dismissing the `UIImagePickerController` because the `UIImagePickerController` dismiss but the second modal view controller doesn't appear.

Comment: That was what I suspected, but as I sample coded right now, it actually does show on my iPhone4 with iOS5. But I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't on iOS4 or before. In that case, I would try adding some delay before presenting the modal view controller by `dispatch_after()` method or `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. The last resort would be hooking to `viewDidAppear` on the view controller that presented the `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I've a tabbarcontroller. In that case I should override viewDidAppear of all view controllers. My bad, why Apple has done this in this complicated way?